# How to dump multiple tables with a where condition into single file

Tags: php, bash, shell, mysql

I have 6 tables named as **table1, table2, table3, table4, table5, table6** and each table contain a field **status** . Before taking the backup i want to check status='N' in each tables. I have the following code

```
mysqldump -t -u root -p dbname table1 -w"Status = 'N'" >/backup/test.sql;
```

this code help only for one table and create 6 file. How can i get the single dump file contain the details of this 6 tables

Comment: Not exactly actually tables like tableA, tableB, tableC, tableD, tableE, tableF. this is the correct scenario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try `mysqldump -t -u root -p dbname table1 table2 table3 table4 table5 table6 -w"Status = 'N'" >/backup/test.sql;`

I think it will meet your requirement..